# run PHP exec command on Windows IIS7

Tags: php, shell, iis, exec

Had issues with running exec() and shell_exec() from php code.
I'm running PHP5.3 on Windows IIS7.
(spent several hours on this and got it finally...)

The following exec() code works:

```
$cmd='cmd.exe /c C:\\<path/to/php/directory/>\php.exe -v';
exec($cmd,$output,$err);
var_dump($output); //dump the output
echo $err; //show the error code, should give 0 for no errors
```

Note i have ensure that:
- The IIS Internet User has the full read+execute rights to the PHP directory
- The IIS Internet User has the full read+execute rights to php.exe
- The IIS Internet User has the full read+execute rights to cmd.exe

If you are outputting alot of data from your background process php file, use shell_exec(), see working code below (at least on my setup):

```
$cmd='cmd.exe /c C:\\<path/to/php/directory/>\php.exe -f C:\\<path\to\your\>\cron.php';
echo shell_exec($cmd); //output the data
```

Note if it returns nothing, means there is something wrong with the path.

Remember to use " \ " (without quotes) to emulate/substitute single backslash " \ " in actual windows paths.

Make sure your background process file i.e. cron.php has permissions for IIS Internet User as well. Have fun!

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question—that's fine but please type the answer in the bottom "Your Answers" text box.

Comment: `php.exe` is an executable file; there's absolutely no need to use `cmd.exe` as proxy. Apart from that, I can't figure out what the question is.